# node js search system regex

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

i have one weird thing in my search system that i noticed:
For example we have two users: Test and test, when i type in my search field test it will show only one user 'test' but page dont showing other Test user...

My whole system is working good but this thing i noticed i and i think it need to show both users..
My current code:

```
users = await User.find({ "name": { $regex: '.*' + search + '.*' }}, '-password');
```

Comment: Is this mongodb?

Comment: Yes, database is mongodb i also use moongose

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it like this

```
const users = await User.find({ 
  name: {
    $regex: '.*' + search + '.*',
    $options: 'i'
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but this didnt solve my problem, with your example my return is empty..With example in my first post everything is fine just this problem with upper and lower letters

Comment: @user15324999 I have updated the answer. Please try this way.

Comment: This time you solved this, thanks alot..Can i ask you one more thing about search system? I used const search = escape(req.query.search); to get search input, and if i have something like 'test test' this is one user and when i type in field 'test test' he dont recognize this spaces.. Any solution for that?

Comment: As the search parameter sent by query param, It will be better to use decodeURI(req.query.search) on the backend side, and encodeURI(search) on the frontend side.

Comment: Thanks alot, i will try :)

Comment: Also, if the issue was solved, please mark as answered.

Comment: Yes i did but im still new here so its not public, please get look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66493164/node-js-moongodb-two-finds