# node.js moongodb two finds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I struggle in last time how to put two find paraments in nodejs:
This is my currently query:

```
userWithCompanies = await User.findById(userId).populate('companies');
```

But in the next i need to make search system here in other sections working search query is for example:

```
companies = await Company.find({title: {$regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: "i"}});
```

So i tried something like this:

```
await User.findById(userId).populate('companies').find({title: {$regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: "i"}});
```

But i just getting error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

Comment: Your two queries above returns different types of records. What are you trying to achieve by combining them? Please describe expected result

Comment: In the first query i getting companies for provided userid, and in last i need to search in that 'companies'.. I hope its clear now what i need here

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide [query condition](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) for populate method. 
Something like this:

```
const userWithCompanies = await User
  .findById(userId)
  .populate({
    path: 'companies',
    match: {
      title: {$regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: "i"}
  });
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this solve my problem and i learned something new :)

Comment: Can u look up at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66531288/node-js-find-query-on-delete-action/66533577#66533577

Comment: @user15324999 I've added a comment to your original post. Please also consider accepting this answer if it solves your problem. Thanks